# How to hide field with label in ctp file in Cakephp?

Tags: cakephp

```
<div><Strong>Name: </strong><?= $record['Childvaccination']['name']; ?></div>
```

When data is not coming then it is showing "Name:" only but I also want to hide name if data is not coming or it is empty.
This is cakephp ctp file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to check if the value is empty or not and output accordingly:-

```
<?php if (!empty($record['Childvaccination']['name'])): ?>
    <div><Strong>Name: </strong><?= $record['Childvaccination']['name']; ?></div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: I'm usually tempted to put this into a custom helper method, with a bit of extra optional arguments where needed.